# Wifi speed is horrible all of the sudden- Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I don't know what happened but all of the sudden (about two days ago) my wifi is absolutely horrible. I asked my coworker if it's working fine for him and he says it's fine. I used Ookla's speed test and get a ping of about 8ms but it doesn't even finish the test. It times out. I get internet here and there but nothing close to even allowing me to use Facebook and Facebook chat. Here's some information for you.

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"My Network"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 06:27:22:F1:4F:B9   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0    
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:113   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

So I tried to get around the wifi issue and plug in an ethernet cord, but it doesn't even detect the ethernet cord. Here's some more info.

```
lshw -C network

  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 9c:d2:1e:3f:4d:14
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=3.13.0-61-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0200000-f0203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: a0:1d:48:e8:e2:05
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=162.211.89.2 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff memory:f0400000-f040ffff
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Some revisions of Realtek NICs do not work well with the standard kernel driver.

So press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

That should solve it!

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**